# Trying to convert diagram of a chess game to java code (abstract)

Tags: java, oop, class-diagram, chess

I am attempting to convert this diagram in to java code just to get a hang of design questions that can be asked.

For instance the Piecetype enum i would write as

```
public enum PieceType{
    pawn, king, queen, rook, bishop, knight
}
```

I was wondering if someone can provide guidance as to how to convert the class diagrams in to the java code just literally take one of the classes shown in the diagram and write the attributes and methods mentioned in java .

I am mostly having hard time figuring out the + and -.

[image]

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers, i am sorry if this was a bad question to ask i am not a regular user of stack over flow . If i somehow i can give you guys reps please let me know. I am trying to add reps but i think i need 15 reps to add .

Comment: Im not sure this is such a terrible question, its well written and despite being asked with respect to your specific problem the idea of reading such a diagram is likely to be of general usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` and `-` refer to visibility:

```
Symbol  Visibility
------  ----------
+       Public 
-       Private 
#       Protected 
/       Derived (can be combined with one of the others)
_       Static
```

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Visibility))

Comment: Thanks so for the board class it would be something like this?

Public Class Board {

Public int Squares [] [] ;

Public PieceSetonTop piececolor;

Public PieceSet pieceset [] ;

public void create(){}

}

Comment: @user1772052 Note that it's `public` (lowercase `p`). And that looks close, just remember that `squares` should be a `Square[][]` not an `int[][]` (by the diagram, at least).

Answer (score 1):

First you should learn how to read the class diagram properly before trying to implement it in Java. The `+` and `-` define the visibility of a class member (e.g. field or method). A `+` denotes a public visible class member, while a `-` represents a private member, i.e. only accessible from the class where it's defined.

Example of conversion to a Java class (`Game`):

```
public class Game {
   private List<Move> playedMoves;
   private PieceColor turn;
   private Players[] players;
   private Result result;
   private CheckStatus checkStatus;

   public Game() {
     playedMoves = new ArrayList<Move>(); // create empty list
     // TODO initialize other fields properly
   }

   public void addMove(Move move) {
     playedMoves.add(move);
   }

   public boolean isCheckmated() {
     return CheckStatus.BlackCheckmated.equals(checkStatus) || 
            CheckStatus.WhiteCheckmated.equals(checkStatus);
   }

   // TODO add other methods
}
```

**References:**

- [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: Amazing Answer Thank you so much!! Just one last question was there are enums for the pieces and such how are they accessed by another class? I am not familiar with enums too much and that is why i am not sure.

Comment: [Enum types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are used in the same way as any other class. They are actually ordinary classes with public static fields of their own type for each constant defined (`PAWN`, `KING`, etc.). You can pass these instances like any other object.